# PHP select different columns with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get all the agenda items. First I have an input with the start date `$start`, but when I have the output (post_id 6 and 14) `post_id`, I want to get the other `meta_value` with the same `post_id` [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F53lM.png).

Here I want to get the `post_id` 6. 
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAdl7.png)

```
$start = $_GET["startDate"];
$end = $_GET["endDate"];
/* Template Name: Example Template */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='eap_from_day' AND '$start' <= DATE(meta_value)";
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$all = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all)) {
    foreach ($row as $r){
        var_dump($r) ;
    }
}
```

How do I get the `meta_value` with the same `post_id` in a Json?

Comment: Add it to the WHERE clause

Comment: (Writing your own queries for stuff like this is not a terribly good idea, you should rather use the functionality WP provides for this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard  If i did i would select only the ```post_id```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i want to get the other collumns"? Do you just want the `meta_key` _names_ of the other columns?  Please update your question to include the desired result/output of the code, as well as where the `post_id` would be set to 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a new query in the while statement:

```
$start = $_GET["startDate"]." "."00:00:00";
$end = $_GET["endDate"]." "."00:00:00";
/* Template Name: Example Template */
//            Events as Posts plugin
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
// conectie word geregeld met de database
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_eventorganiser_schedule_start_start' AND '$start' <= DATE(meta_value)AND '$end' >= DATE(meta_value)";
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$all = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all)) {
    foreach ($row as $r) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '$r'";
        $everything = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($everything)) {
            $sql3 = "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = '$r'";
            $last = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
            while ($rest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last)) {
                $title= $rest["post_title"];
                $info= $rest["post_content"];

                if ($col["meta_key"] == "_eventorganiser_schedule_start_start") {
                    $date = $col["meta_value"];
                }
                if ($col["meta_key"] == "_eventorganiser_schedule_last_finish") {
                 $enddate = $col["meta_value"];
                }
                $result = array("title"=>$title,"info"=>$info,"begindatum"=> $date,"einddatum"=>$enddate);
            }
        }print_r(json_encode($result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='eap_from_day' AND '$start' <= DATE(meta_value) and post_id=6";`

Comment: it is already selecting post_id 6 i only want to select the rest of the collums with post_id 6

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah got you it's easy just change SELECT post_id to SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='eap_from_day' AND '$start' <= DATE(meta_value) AND post_id='6' ";
```

That's what you want?